# Create matrix of strings by a method analogous to matrix multiplication

Tags: string-manipulation

I have 2 lists of strings, say, the first is `{"D1","D2","D3"}` and the second is `{"P1", "P2","P3"}`.  I want to create

> ```
> D1P1  D1P2  D1P3  
> D2P1  P2P2  D2P3  
> D3P1  D3P2  D3P3
> ```

where the elements `"D1P1"`, etc., are strings.  This seems to call for something analogous to matrix outer multiplication, but using `String Concatenation` instead of `Times`.  How might I do this?

Comment: Try 'Table[i<>j, {i,list1},{j,list2}]'

Comment: `Outer[StringJoin, {"D1", "D2", "D3"}, {"P1", "P2", "P3"}]`

Answer (score 5):

Using [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html),

```
Outer[StringJoin, {"D1", "D2", "D3"}, {"P1", "P2", "P3"}]
(* {{"D1P1", "D1P2", "D1P3"}, {"D2P1", "D2P2", "D2P3"}, {"D3P1",
   "D3P2", "D3P3"}} *)

MatrixForm@%
```

[image]